# Forma correta de se utilizar try except

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou trabalhando pela primeira vez com uma API e preciso retornar um erro caso ocorra, a seguir o meu código com a forma mais clara e simples que encontrei de notificar os erros:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                    information = json.loads(request.data)
                    string_open = information['before']
                    string_closed = information['after']
            except:
                    return 'Não foi possivel interpretar a requisição'


            try:
                    results_open = tfnet.return_predict(readb64(string_open))
                    results_closed = tfnet.return_predict(readb64(string_closed))
            except:
                    return 'Não foi possível converter a string64'

return jsonify(result_inventory)
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma melhor de escrever esse código ou alguma convenção que regularize o tratamento de exceções no python.

Comment: Se eu chamar essa função, como saberei, a partir do retorno, se deu erro ou não na chamada à API? Como poderei diferenciar se a *string* que foi retornada é devido a um erro ou se foi de fato o retorno da API? Aliás, o que são `jsonify` e `result_inventory` que não estão definidos no código?

Comment: jsonify é o método do flask para retornar json, result_inventory é basicamente um json. Então se retornar uma json no formato esperado deu certo, caso contrario ele vai retornar uma string dependendo de onde ocorreu o erro.

Comment: Então não seria interessante deixar a exceção propagar para fora da função e deixar quem está chamando-a tratar isso? Não parece fazer muito sentido capturar uma exceção apenas para notificar um erro.

Comment: Mas tentar perceber pelo resultado se é string normal ou json é pior e mais trabalhoso que capturar a exceção no local onde é chamada a função.

Comment: Certo, então a melhor forma de lidar com isso seria retornar o próprio erro ?

Comment: A melhor forma é deixar a exceção ser propagada para fora da função, como o @AndersonCarlosWoss mencionou.